# Java Access array elements from an object array containing an object containing a double array in Intellij

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea

Backstory: I have a spring boot app that gets the input parameters of any method that is annotated with a custom annotation. It places the types of those parameters in a Class Array `clazz` and values in the Object array `obj`.

This is generalized so elements in obj can be arrays, such as:

```
clazz = {int, java.lang.String, [D}
obj = {2, "Foobar", [3.1415, 2.718]}
```

I am trying to print out all the elements in obj with the following code. Note that clazz and obj always have the same lengths, and the same indices are related to each other (see above example).

The code checks to see if the Object is an array as not to print something like [D@431621

```
private void othermethod(Class[] clazz, Object[] obj){

    for(int i =0 ; i<clazz.length;i++){
        if(clazz[i].isArray()){
            System.out.println(ObjArrayDisplay(obj[i], clazz[i]));
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(obj[i].toString());
        }
    }
}

private String ObjArrayDisplay(Object o, Class c){
    //Option 1. return Arrays.deepToString((Object[])o);java.lang.ClassCastException: [D cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
    //Option 2. return Arrays.deepToString(c.cast(o)); deepToString (java.lang.Object[]) in Arrays cannot be applied to (java.lang.Object)
}
```

And therein lies the problem.

Let's return to the example values:

```
clazz = {int, java.lang.String, [D}
obj = {2, "Foobar", [3.1415, 2.718]}
```

Option 1: For this clazz and obj, the code compiles, but when the code gets to the Double array, it can't be cast back to an Object array, as Double extends Object.

Option 2:  This time the code doesn't even compile due to a syntax error: Arrays.deepToString expects an Object array but before runtime the syntax checker only sees Object. It's not until after runtime that a Double[] wrapped in an Object gets sent down the stack.

This would also be a problem with other data structures like Hashmap, ArrayList.

Is there someway to get the elements of Object o? I have no control over what primitive types or objects are inputs for the annotated methods, so changing clazz and obj are not an option.

**Edit:** Spring boot class that provides clazz (ie classes) and obj (ie params)

```
@Aspect
@Component
@Getter
public class Flow {
    @Autowired
    SubscriptionsIntegration SI;

    private Class[] classes;
    private Object[] params;
    private Object returnvalue = "Start";

    @Around("@annotation(TrackFlow)")
    public Object TrackFlow(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable{

        CodeSignature cs = (CodeSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();

        classes = cs.getParameterTypes();
        params = joinPoint.getArgs();

        Object proceed = joinPoint.proceed();

        returnvalue = proceed;

        return proceed;
    }
}
```

**Edit 2:** Found the solution in an obscure maven dependency, and posted it here.

Comment: Java is a strongly typed language, so doing something like this will always be tricky. What is it exactly that you are trying to achieve with these arrays of clazz and object? Maybe there is a better data structure to store them in?

Comment: It's an output from a Spring Aspect class with the @Around annotation which gets the input parameters from any method annotated with a custom annotation.

This is the class in question that gives me clazz and obj: Edit, now also added to original post

Comment: AtAspect
AtComponent
AtGetter
public class Flow {
    @Autowired
    SubscriptionsIntegration SI;

    private Class[] classes;
    private Object[] params;
    private Object returnvalue = "Start";

    @Around("@annotation(TrackFlow)")
    public Object TrackFlow(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable{

        CodeSignature cs = (CodeSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
        classes = cs.getParameterTypes();
        params = joinPoint.getArgs();

        Object proceed = joinPoint.proceed();
        returnvalue = proceed;
        return proceed;
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution to my own post. For future reference, turns out there is a Maven Jackson dependency that can do this

```
@Autowired
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper objectMapper;

//...other methods and variables

private String ObjArrayDisplay(Object o, Class c){
    String returnValue = null;
    try {
        returnValue = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(o);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you could use a wrapper class and print it's toString

```
class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Double[] objects = {2.02,2.22,2.13};
        System.out.print(new Foo(objects));

        String[] strings = {"array","of", "strings"};
        System.out.print(new Foo(strings));

    }

    public static class Foo{
        private Object[] objects;
        public Foo(Object[] objects){
            this.objects=objects;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Foo{" +
                    "objects=" + Arrays.toString(objects) +
                    '}';
        }
    }
}
```

You mentioned that you can't control if it's primitives but they will not be passed into `private void othermethod(Class[] clazz, Object[] obj)` because they will not be an array of objects.

Comment: The Object array obj can contain anything from primitives to Objects to Object arrays, in my original post, I mentioned how an element of obj that is a double array could not be cast back into an object array due to inheritance.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. An double[] is not a Object[] but an Double[] is an Object[]. Int is primitive and Integer is not. So if you have a method with a parameter of Object[] objects and you tried to pass double[] doubles into it, it would not compile

Comment: Yes you're technically right about primitives, though java converts primitives that are assigned to Objects to their Object form, so a primitive array cast to an object array is functionally the same and would compile. In any case I found a solution to the problem.